# Validate the correctness of for loop translation of below mentioned list compression

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have translated the list compression code `[num for elem in vec for num in elem]` to a for loop as below.

```
listnew = []
for elem in vec:
    for num in elem:
        listnew.append(num)
```

The above for-loop produced same result as the list compression.Is this the correct implementation of the above list compression or if there are better way i can translate the list compression, do let me know?

Comment: This is indeed a rigorous translation of the list comprehension. But the difference is that by using a list-comprehension, the `.append(..)` is done by the interpreter itself and thus will boost performance. Why do you want to translate it into loops?

Comment: Translation is definitely for learning purpose, to see how the list comprehension can be implemented using for loop

Answer (score 0):

What you present here is indeed the *rigorous* translation of the list comprehension: so this is more or less what happens behind the curtains of the Python interpreter.

In general the [*grammar* in Python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html) for *list comprehension* is defined like:

atom → `[` [listmaker] `]`
listmaker → test ( list_for | (`,` test)* [`,`] )
list_for → `for` exprlist `in` testlist_safe [list_iter]
list_iter → list_for | list_if
list_if → `if` old_test [list_iter]

Here "test" and "old_test" are more or less a generic expressions (yes there are some differences, but let's ignore that now). If we simplify the grammar a bit, a list comprehension looks like:

```
[<expr> for <x-1> in <iter-1> (for <x-i> in <iter-i> | if <expr-i>)*]
```

This is syntax for an `<expr> for <x-1> for <iter-1>` followed by zero or more `for <x-i> in <iter-i>`s and `if <expr-i>`s (that can be interleaved in every possible way).

The Python interpreter will behind the curtains perform something like:

```
result = []
for <x-1> in <iter-1>:
    (for <x-i> in <iter-i> | if <expr-i>):
        result.append(<expr>)
```

So list comprehension like:

```
[x*y for x in list1 if x > 1 for y in list2 if y < 10 if x > y]
```

would be translated into:

```
result = []
for x in list1:
    if x > 1:
        for y in list2:
            if y < 10:
                if x > y:
                    result.append(x*y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.As you mentioned my translation is  rigorous, please provide a simpler version of the above translation.